# GetAllPaths from an sourceEdge to a destinationEdge

Tags: python, sumo

im really looking for a solution to my problem, the thing is im new to sumo and i want to find a way to get all the possible paths between two edges.
Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what do you mean exactly by "all paths". There may be indefinitely many if you allow streets to occur multiple times. If you forbid multiple occurrences of the same edge you can use the findAllRoutes.py script in the tools directory of SUMO like that:

```
tools/findAllRoutes.py -n my.net.xml -s source -t target -o routes.rou.xml
```

where source and target are the ids of the respective edges in the SUMO network.

Please be aware that there may be *many* different routes so make sure you have enough disk space if you have a large network.

Comment: Exactly i used this, but it generates a lot of routes between two edges, and we have to work with the cmd to get the file, for me, i want to use the same logic of this but i dont want to work with files and cmd, i want to write a script similar to "findAllRoutes.py" but i don't have the skills for this. If you have any idea how to deal with that I'd be thankful.

Comment: The script is by no means complex. If you strip the comments and the option parsing it has maybe 30 lines so feel free to port that to whatever different scripting you like. The fact that there are a lot of routes has nothing to do with the script though: "all routes" can be a lot (exponentially many in fact).